# Is there some workaround to pass primitive variables by reference?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, reference, primitive

I have searched the internet and found nothing.

This is the example of what i want:

```
test() {
        var a = 1;
        var b = a;
        b = 2;
        console.log(a);  //I want the output is 2 and not 1
    }
```

I know that objects and arrays are passed by reference and would solve the problem but i cant use that aproach.

I hope to have explained my problem well .

Comment: *"i cant use that aproach [sic]"* - why not? What are you actually trying to achieve with this?